# Securely storage

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My app contain a security key which I need to send every time I call web service.
The code is not provided by the user, it's in the code and it won't be changed.
For now I store the key as a string in code.

I need to store it somewhere, the ideal solution would be .config file where I could store it in appSettings and I could also encode the file. I know that there is not such a file available in WP, but what is the WP alternative.

Do you know any way I can securely store the security key?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need to store some passwords/credentials, then take a look at [PasswordVault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx), also some information [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465069.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of securely storing the key with your `xap`, use your server to distribute key to the app.

When your app opens for the first time, get the key from server, encrypt it and store it in `IsolatedStorageSettings`. For subsequent app sessions, decrypt and use the same.

The current scenario is, all `XAP`s on store are encrypted and there is no way to get access to your dll without interop unlock. However, if you are not doing a Silverlight application and instead do a WinRT application, the APPX package is not encrypted and anyone can download it from the store.

If you are going with a Silverlight app, it is secure enough to put the key in `IsolatedStorageSettings` after encrypting. If it is a WinRT app, you can get the key from your server.

Comment: The whole reason for storing the key inside the app is to make sure that the http request is signed (HMAC) with this key. If I try fetch the key from the server it's going to be less secure because I won't be signed the request for the first time with the call to obtain the key. PS. I'm working on WiRT app.